# Debian with "APT::Install-Recommends "false";" wants to autoremove packages installed with --install-recommends

Tags: apt

right after my system installation, I add

```
"APT::Install-Recommends "false";"
```

to APT settings.

Recently I installed "nvidia-driver" package with

```
# apt install --install-recommends nvidia-driver
```

because in this case  this was what I wanted. There was only two Recommended package (nvidia-settings and nvidia-persistenced), that I could install manually, but doing it this way this install all packages with Recommends recursively.

However I was expecting that recommended packages installed this way were considered main dependencies., but this is not the case. All these packages are marked 'auto', but they are not considered a dependency for their main package, and are all showing as auto-removable. This is a pain because I can't use autoremove any more.

I know I can installed these recommended packages manually to overcome this problem, but my question is about apt, is there any settings that change this behavior for packages installed with "--install-recommends" so they do not appears in autoremove list?